# Selecting folders, not files, in Google Chrome

Tags: java, javascript, actionscript, google-chrome

I'm creating an extension for Google Chrome, so any code has to be compatible with Chrome and Chrome only. In this extension, I need the user to select a folder from his local machine. This simple task is becoming quite a problem. The chrome extensions options page will not run applets, so I couldn't really do Java. It's Google Chrome only so an ActiveX object is out of the question as well. I just need a simple way of selecting a folder(not a file) and passing its path to Javascript. Might this be possible in Flash Actionscript? It seems FileReference and FileReferenceList classes in AS only allow you to choose a file, and not a folder. Is there another possibility besides Flash? All the options page files DO rest on the local users machine, so it's not server side.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It seems like FileReference doesn't let you get full path anyway.. So I guess AS is out of the question too...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the webkit-directory attribute on your  element to select directories and get the same sort of result as from the "multiple" attribute.

A demo of this: http://www.thecssninja.com/demo/webkitdirectory/

The chromium bug: http://crbug.com/58977